# global mouse hook suddenly not getting called

Tags: c#, mouse, hook

I have a global mouse hook in my app but after sometime (on some computers) the mouse hook procedure (MouseHookProc) suddenly stops getting called, I'm not sure why, I've searched for the reason and it seems like it has something to do with win7's LowLevelHooksTimeout

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

private void AddMouseHook()
{
    MouseHookProcedure = new User32.HookProc(MouseHookProc);
    hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookProcedure, (IntPtr)null, 0);
}
```

fix seems to be to add the mouse hook in a new thread but if I do that then the mouse hook doesn't gets called right from the beginning, and I can verify that SetWindowsHookEx does return value > 0 so hook got added properly, but again if it's added from another thread then "MouseHookProc" doesn't get invoked even once, if started from main thread then no problem, but just disappears after sometime (mostly after some heavy processing where my mouse will tend to freeze then after that "MouseHookProc" will not be called anymore

```
ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(AddMouseHook);
Thread th = new Thread(ts);
th.Start();
```

Comment: This blog shows how to do/start mouse hook in a new thread, http://strakh.com/2010/07/14/async-windowshook-at-wpf-applications/, although even after doing that, mouse hook procedure still stops getting called after mouse freezes at any point in time :-(